# laravel 5.6: Many to Many relationship sync

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many

I create 3 tables

```
articles : id title

category: id name

article_category:  id article_id category_id main
```

And in `Category` model:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
}
```

I want add data to `article_category`:

```
$article_id = 20;
$category_id = 1;
$category = Category::find($category_id);
$cat[$article_id] = ['main'=>false];
$category ->articles()->sync($cat);

$article_id = 20;
$category_id = 2;
$category = Category::find($category_id);
$cat[$article_id] = ['main'=>false];
$category ->articles()->sync($cat);
```

Now In `article_category` I have:

```
article_id    category_id   main
20              1           false
20              2           false
```

Ok It seems normal.

for example if add this again:

```
$article_id = 20;
$category_id = 2;
$category = Category::find($category_id);
$cat[$article_id] = ['main'=>false];
$category ->articles()->sync($cat);
```

It not generate duplication rows.

**Now my problem is this:**

If I add a new article_id, It remove all last saved records.

for example with add these codes:

```
$article_id = 21;
$category_id = 1;
$category = Category::find($category_id);
$cat[$article_id] = ['main'=>false];
$category ->articles()->sync($cat);

$article_id = 21;
$category_id = 2;
$category = Category::find($category_id);
$cat[$article_id] = ['main'=>false];
$category ->articles()->sync($cat);
```

I expect this:

```
article_id    category_id   main
20              1           false
20              2           false
21              1           false
21              2           false
```

But In my databse I have this:

article_id    category_id   main
21              1           false
21              2           false

what's my wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation in [Laravel 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships), ***Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table***. It will only make many to many relation for category_id in which $cat variable contains its respective id.

This is why, it will remove all last saved records when adding a new article.

If you want to attach the new relationship, simply use

```
 $category->articles()->syncWithoutDetaching($cat);
```